# How do I pull in form data via AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, post

I am a brand new TA for ExactTarget, so AMPScript is very new to me.  I have a web page which has a `<textarea>`.  Users can go in and copy/paste a list of domains to this `<textarea>` (upwards of possibly 10,000 at a time).  So when the user clicks Submit, I want my AMPScript to get that form data.  I understand (I believe) how `REQUESTPARAMETER(...)` works, but I don't think that will work for HTTP POST data, right?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RequestParameter](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#RequestParameter) pulls from both the query string and the form data, and I have used both (though I'm not sure what would happen if you had one in each with the same name).

I have a page with a hidden field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="AMPScript " id="AMPScript " value="http://www.yahoo.com"/>
```

When I post, I get the data out using AMPScript like this:

```
%%[

   SET @TempContent = RequestParameter("AMPScript ")

]%%
```

It works great.  Hope this helps!